# Uninstalling bower installed with a different version of npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, bower, version-compatibility

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 system. I had installed npm and I installed bower using

```
sudo npm install -g bower
```

Some time after that I realized that I was using the node and npm that came fromt he ubuntu repositories, so to use the latest one, I added the repository:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

and update the packages.

Now I was trying to uninstall bower from the system, but guess what? I get this:

```
$ sudo npm remove -g bower
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/lib/node_modules: "bower"
```

So, wait, what? It cant find Bower? So I try to make

```
which bower
```

and the output here is:

```
/usr/local/bin/bower
```

I dont really understand what is going on. I suspect that I have a problem with different versions of npm and nodejs not playing nice together, since I installed bower with a different version of `npm` that the one I have installed now. Any idea of how I could uninstall Bower now? (Or at least come back to a clean state, so that I can begin from the beginning?)

Comment: Just a blind guess, you installed with `sudo` so directories may differ. And/or your current user can't search the sudo-path where it was installed.

Comment: just a note, in windows you can use `where bower`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`sudo npm uninstall bower -g --prefix=/usr/local`

Comment: I love you, @npm_support :)